# Wordpress multisite redirects subpages to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

**Summary of the problem:** I have a new wordpress multisite set up as subdirectories (same base URL with languages subdirectories, like domain.com/en-gb/ for example), it's working fine in itself apart from this one very annoying issue: 
**Everytime I am trying to access a subpage of the main domain (like domain.com/page/ or domain.com/wp-config for example), it redirects to the homepage of this domain (domain.com).**

**Observation 1:** This weirdly only happens the first time you try to load a subpage of the main domain on a tab. Like for example, you are on facebook, see an ad, click on the link domain.com/subpage, or say you open a blank tab and type domain.com/wp-admin, you get redirected to domain.com. BUT THEN, if now from this tab you try to go to the subpage (any subpage), it works fine. That's only happening the first time you load the domain on the page.

**Observation 2:** I think the problem started when I enabled SSL with the plugin Really Simple SSL (which maybe doesn't supports well the multisite, I don't know). I tried deleting its part of the .htaccess file, but that didn't solve anything. I am not 100% sure that it worked before enabling Really Simple SSL, but I have a feeling it's involved somehow. I don't know if it adds anything else than the lines in .htaccess (like some redirection in the database maybe?).

**Observation 3:** This problem doesn't seem to affect the subdirectories. For example, if I go to domain.com/en-gb/page, that works as it should, even on a new blank tab. It seems that only the main domain is concerned.

**Permalinks are set to Custom : /%postname%/**

Server Info: Apache
Hosting company: OVH
PHP Version: 7.3.6
MySQL vesion: 5.6.43

Here is the **.htaccess** (with Really Simple SSH part already deleted) :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# END ShortPixelWebp
```

Just FYI, this was what **Really Simple SSH** added at the beggining of .htaccess (that I deleted) :

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.2.2]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
```

And here is the **wp-config.php** (without logins) :

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'XXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'XXXXXXXXXXXX');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'mod155_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.XXXXXXXXXXXX.co');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://www.XXXXXXXXXXXX.co' );

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/* Fixes "Add media button not working", see http://www.carnfieldwebdesign.co.uk/blog/wordpress-fix-add-media-button-not-working/ */
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

That is really annoying and is obviously lowering the conversion rate of the main website (because all the trafic is redirected to homepage no matter what)

Could you help me solve this? I have all access across the whole website / database, so I can try anything.

Thanks in advance,
Maxime

Answer (score 0):

So, to anyone wondering, after a bunch of tests, I was able to narrow the error and finally understand and be able to fully replicate it.

The real problem under it was that it was redirecting any url that didn't have the "www." before it (I set my url with www. when doing the config).

So here's how I solved it: 
I went to my .htaccess and set it like this instead :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So now what this does is that it redirects all urls (with or without www. and with or without https) to https://www.

And that solved it